# Recursive flatten nested objects in an array of object

Tags: javascript, nested-object

I've been trying to create a dynamic function which could flatten an nested key/val object inside an array of objects

How do I get this structure? Knowing that i would like to call the keys dynamically and bind the parent key and child key with an _.

Input:

```
const list = [
    {
        month: 'Jan', 
        value: 20, 
        metric: { 
            name: 'Rice', 
            measurement: 'Kg', 
            is_currency: false 
        },
        entity: { 
            name: 'Rev', 
            type: 'limited company'
        }
    },
    {
        month: 'Jan', 
        value: 1000, 
        metric: { 
            name: 'Revenue', 
            measurement: 'Dollars', 
            is_currency: true
        },
        entity: { 
            name: 'Rev', 
            type: 'limited company'
        }
    },
]
```

Expected output:

```
const list = [
    {
        month: 'Jan', 
        value: 20, 
        metric_name: 'Rice',
        metric_measurement: 'Kg', 
        metric_currency: false,
        entity_name: 'Rev', 
        entity_type: 'limited company'
    },
    {
        month: 'Jan', 
        value: 1000, 
        metric_name: 'Revenue', 
        metric_measurement: 'Dollars', 
        metric_is_currency: true
        entity_name: 'Rev', 
        entity_type: 'limited company'
    },
]
```

Comment: That sounds like a homework problem.

Comment: Please show any attempt that you have made to solve this issue yourself.  You are expected to have made an attempt that we can then help you debug.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users  Also review [ask]

Comment: `const flatObj = (obj, keyPrefix = null) => Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key, val]) => {
    if(typeof val !== 'object') {
        return { ...acc, [keyPrefix ? \`${keyPrefix}_${key}\`: key]: val }
    } else {
        return { ...acc, ...flatObj(val, keyPrefix ? \`${keyPrefix}_${key}\` : key) }
    }
}, {})`

`list.map(item => flatObj(item))`